# How to move the data lables to the center in react apex charts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts

How can I place pie chart data labels on the center.

Here is my pie chart looks like.
[image]

The data label values are stuck on to the border of the chart. How can I move them a little bit to the center?

Here is my code.

```
import React from "react";
import Chart from "react-apexcharts";

const TopAttackVector = () => {
  return (
    <div className="font">
      <Chart
        className="mx-96"
        type="pie"
        width={450}
        height={250}
        series={[30, 30, 30]}
        options={{
          labels: [
            "Stolen Credentials",
            "Business Disruption",
            "Data Compromise",
          ],
          colors: ["#ce9f2c", "#062341", "#00BFFF", "#229466"],
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            offsetX: 30,
            style: {
              fontSize: "16px",
              fontFamily: "Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif",
              fontWeight: "bold",
            },
          },
          stroke: {
            width: 0,
          },
          legend: {
            fontSize: "14px",
            fontWeight: "bold",
            itemMargin: "left",
          },
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default TopAttackVector;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `dataLabels` `offset` in `plotOptions` https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/plotoptions/pie/#dataLabelsOffset

```
plotOptions: {
  pie: {
    dataLabels: {
      offset: -50,
    }, 
  }
}
```